# Video showing up as Audio in media library

Tags: media-scanner, media-files

I use Jelly Bean on my Galaxy Nexus.

I have copied a .avi File to the 'Movies'-folder of the device using mtpfs. I expected the file to show up as a Video in the Media Library so I can use Skifta (a DLNA server) to stream it to my TV.

Instead it showed up as Audio and therefore it cannot be watched. I can view the movie on the TV if I use a DLNA server on my desktop and I can view it on android if I use vlc.

So I am wondering if there is a way to manually manage the media library and add the file as a video or to force the media scanner to classify the file as a video? I have already tried renaming to '.mp4' without success.

Comment: Did you ever get any help with this issue?